# Filtro de busca flexível

Tags: php, mysql, filtro

Tenho uma página com um filtro de busca com as opções de "serviço", "estado" e "cidade" e um botão submit que redireciona pra página onde vai aparecer uma tabela com os cadastros já filtrados.

Porém atualmente o filtro só funciona se o usuário preencher só o serviço, ou serviço e estado ou serviço e estado e cidade, o que impede que ele busque todos os serviços que existem naquele estado ou naquele estado e cidade.

Queria saber como eu faço pra fazer com que o filtro continue funcionando pra caso o usuário preencha só o serviço, ou serviço e estado, ou serviço estado e cidade e também passe a funcionar pra caso o usuário preencha só o serviço ou estado e cidade.

Esse é o código do filtro:

```
<!-- - - - - - Esse é o teste do filtro - - - - - - -->
<?
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'db_qualquer') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY servico, estado, cidade ASC';
    $servico = isset($_POST['servico']) ? $_POST['servico'] : null;
    $estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : null;
    $cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : null;
    $arrParams = array();


    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE ";
    if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)){
        $arrParams[] = array (
            'filter' => 'servico',
            'value' => $servico
        );
    }
    if (!is_null($estado) && !empty($estado) && $cidade == 'none' && $estado != 'none') {
        $arrParams[] = array (
            'filter' => 'estado',
            'value' => $estado
        );
    }

    if ( !is_null($estado) && !empty($estado) && !is_null($cidade) && !empty($cidade) && $cidade != 'none') {
        $arrParams[] = array (
            'filter' => 'estado',
            'value' => $estado
        );
        $arrParams[] = array (
            'filter' => 'cidade',
            'value' => $cidade
        );
    }
    $cont = 1;
    $total = count($arrParams);

    foreach($arrParams as $param){

        $sqli .= $param['filter'] . " LIKE '%".$param['value']."%'";
        if ($total > 1 && $cont != $total) {
            $sqli.= "AND ";
        }
        $cont ++;
    } 

    $qry = mysqli_query($link, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    //$fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    }

?>
```

Se alguém puder me dar alguma dica seria legal.

Comment: coloque um echo($sqli) após o  mysqli_query(...) e coloque  o que está sendo printado na tela para que possamos ver a query

Comment: Oi! Tentei pesquisar preenchendo só o filtro de estado e deu: SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '%Selecione...%'AND estado LIKE '%Rio de Janeiro%'